# PHP array re-sort when changing a value

Tags: php, sorting, foreach

My solution works when sorting to the top, but, unfortunately, is not stable. I can not find my mistake.

I get something like that when I sort up, example 4 to 1:

```
['sort'] => 1
['sort'] => 1
['sort'] => 2
['sort'] => 3
```

The field is always moved correctly. Where is the mistake in this function? It is important that the sorting value should not occur twice or more.

The functionality is very simple.

If the users create a new field or for existing fields to change the sorting and if this sort number already exists I would move the field and re-sort all other fields `$sArr['sort']`.

Sorting should always be as follows:

```
['sort'] => 1
['sort'] => 2
['sort'] => 3
['sort'] => 4
```

$sArr, my array variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58c6bea7c8d666.74251302
            [sort] => 3
            [name] => Field 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58c6beac86a786.66634467
            [sort] => 1
            [name] => Field 2 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58c6beb027d915.29472725
            [sort] => 2
            [name] => Field 1 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58c6beb755e690.35545890
            [sort] => 4
            [name] => Field 3 
        )

)
```

$sField:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 58c6beb755e690.35545890
    [sort] => 1
    [name] => Field 3 
)
```

PHP:

```
protected function _reArrange($sArr, $sField, $sPos)
{
    if (!isset($sArr) || !is_array($sArr)) {
        return false;
    }
    $sFieldCnt = count($sArr);
    if ($sPos < 0 || $sPos >= $sFieldCnt) {
        return false;
    }
    $iCurrentPos = -1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $sFieldCnt; $i++) {
        if ($sArr[$i]['id'] === $sField['id']) {
            $iCurrentPos = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($iCurrentPos == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($iCurrentPos == $sPos) {
        return true;
    }
    $sField = $sArr[$iCurrentPos];
    if ($iCurrentPos < $sPos) {
        for ($i = $iCurrentPos; $i < $sPos; $i++) {
            $sArr[$i] = $sArr[$i + 1];
            $sArr[$i]['sort'] = $i + 1;
        }
        $sArr[$sPos] = $sField;
        return true;
    } else {
        for ($i = $iCurrentPos; $i > $sPos; $i--) {
            $sArr[$i] = $sArr[$i - 1];
            $sArr[$i]['sort'] = $i - 1;
        }
        $sArr[$sPos] = $sField;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: I get something like that when I sort up, example 4 to 1. (1, 1, 2, 3)

Where is the mistake in this function?

Comment: It is important that the sorting value should not occur twice or more.